# Best way to merge Excel files in a single Excel file

Tags: java, excel, algorithm, aspose

I'm working on a feature in an application that allows to read Excel files and merge them into a new single file, during the transfer of data from the Excel source file to the target Excel, There are mainly changes in index columns, for example, we puts data of the first to the tenth column.

My question is what is the right way to do this?

I hesitate between these two solutions:

Use DTOs:

- Read source Excel file and put them in a List
- Do all modifications in this list
- Fill the target Excel file by data from the list

Use Map:

- Put target column index as key and source column index as value
- Read file row by row and fill the target Excel file

What's the best solution from a performance and maintainability point of view?

Comment: With a Map you pay the penalty when you build the map but you reap the benefits when you read from the map, with a list it's the reverse (no penalty for connecting two lists, but you pay the penalty when you search for the cell you are looking for).  What is the state of the data in its original location? Is it already sorted, will you be jumping around a lot while you are connecting the two tables?

Comment: I consider DTOs far better for maintainability and would refuse to believe performance penalties unless proven wrong from a profiler (we could talk about a hypthothetical perfomance benefits, but I consider this a form of premature optimazation).

Comment: @JasonSperske In the original location the data are not stored, for each row there are multiple modifications from the source and the target files, for example we put data of the second column from the source file in the third column of the target.

Comment: @tilois in our app, the performance is the important criterion, because we deal with very big Excel files.

Comment: @tilois the performance characteristics aren't insignificant, but depending on the size of the data the problem could be very small or very large.  Java has some great implementations of Collections (Sets, Maps etc) so the complexity of either approach likely isn't an issue, however depending on how the final code is structured a good Map class can make code easier to reason about.  That ease and speed isn't free however (maps take up more memory than arrays).  Personally I would start with a Map (because of simplicity) and only optimize to a list if memory becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Aspose.Cells for Java's *Workbook.combine* method that allows to efficiently combine two Workbooks (spreadsheets) into one. Please check the following piece of code that combines two spreadsheets and saves the result onto the disk.

```
Workbook book1 = new Workbook(sample1);
Workbook book2 = new Workbook(sample2);
book1.combine(book2);
book1.save("D:/output.xls");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution cannot help me, there are some treatments to do in the columns data during the merge.